# Problems with resolving a while loop for a menu

Tags: java

I´m a beginner at JAVA and I´m doing an assignment for my class. I have a problem that I can´t solve.

The assignment is to create methods to be called from a menu and to jump back to the menu after return of the methods. I got the program to return to menu but I get an error at the same time. I would like to solve this using a do while loop but if its not possible please recommend another way.

As a bonus I would like to be prompted to hit  to go back to the menu. This is not really necessary for the assignment but I think it would look a lot better.

```
System.out.println("Välkommen till calculus. Dina val är:");
boolean loop = true;
do
{
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("1) Beräkna ett klots volym.");
System.out.println("2) Beräkna en cylinders volym.");
System.out.println("3) Bråktal.");
System.out.println("4) Summera.");
System.out.println("5) Räta linjen ekvation.");
System.out.println("6) Avsluta programmet.");
System.out.print("Vad vill du göra (1-6): ");


int val = in.nextInt();
if (val == 6)
{
    loop = false;
}
else
{
    if (val == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Vad är klotets radie (heltal): ");
        int radie = in.nextInt();
        if (radie > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Klotets volym är: " + Math.round(volume(radie) * 100.0) / 100.0);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Du har matat in ett felaktigt värde!");
        }

    }
else
    if (val == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Vad är cylinderns radie (heltal): ");
        int radie = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Vad är cylinderns höjd (heltal): ");
        int hojd = in.nextInt();
        if (radie > 0 && hojd > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Cylinderns volym är: " + Math.round(volume(radie,hojd) * 100.0 ) /100.0);           }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Du har matat in ett felaktigt värde!");
        }

    }
else
    if (val == 3)
    {
        System.out.println("Vad är täljaren (heltal): ");
        int talj = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Vad är nämnaren (heltal): ");
        int namn = in.nextInt();
        if (talj != 0 && namn != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Resultatet är: " + (fraction(talj,namn)));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Du har matat in ett felaktigt värde!");
        }

    }
else
    if (val == 4)
    {
        System.out.println("vad är heltalet: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        if (n > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Resultatet är: " + (sum(n)));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Du har matat in ett felaktigt värde!");
        }

    }

} 
in.close();     
} while (loop == true);
}
/**
Beräknar ett klots volym
@param radie positiv integer
@return positiv double
 */
public static double volume(int radie)
{
    return (4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radie, 3)) / 3;
}

/**
Beräknar en cylinders volym
@param radie positiv integer
@param hojd positiv integer
@return positiv double
 */
public static double volume(int radie ,int hojd)
{
    return Math.PI * Math.pow(radie, 2) * hojd;
}
/**
Presenterar heltal och bråktal av en täljare och nämnare
@param talj positiv integer
@param namn positiv integer
@return string
 */
public static String fraction(int talj ,int namn)
{
    int heltal = talj / namn;
    int brak = talj % namn;
    if (heltal == 0)
    {
        return brak + "/" + namn;
    }
    else
        if (brak == 0)
        {
            return heltal + " ";
        }
    else
        {
            return heltal + " " + brak + "/" + namn;
        }
}
/**
Summerar alla heltal upp till inmatat heltal
@param n positiv integer
@return positiv integer
 */
public static int sum(int n)
{
    int summa = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        summa = summa + i;
    }
    return summa;
}
```

the error I get looks like this:

Välkommen till calculus. Dina val är:

1) Beräkna ett klots volym.

2) Beräkna en cylinders volym.

3) Bråktal.

4) Summera.

5) Räta linjen ekvation.

6) Avsluta programmet.

Vad vill du göra (1-6): 4

vad är heltalet:

4

Resultatet är: 10

1) Beräkna ett klots volym.

2) Beräkna en cylinders volym.

3) Bråktal.

4) Summera.

5) Räta linjen ekvation.

6) Avsluta programmet.

Vad vill du göra (1-6): Exception in thread "main" 
java.util.NoSuchElementException

```
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

at Calculus.main(Calculus.java:31)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` to before `do` and `in.close();` to after `} while (loop == true);` (basically, move the `Scanner` instantiation and closing to outside of the `do-while` loop.